# NOT IN query not match values in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query is:

```
select * from customer_purchase_order  where purchase_id NOT IN (SELECT cus_po_no FROM cus_comercial_invoice)
```

In this purchase id is single values but cus_po_no are multiple in cus_comercial_invoice table.

For example:

```
Purchase_id 1: POV162031.
Purchase_id 2: POV162125.

cus_po_no : 'POV162031','POV162125'.
```

Not In Query Not working

Comment: Are `purchase_id` and `cus_po_no` same type?

Comment: If you post stacktrace it will be easy to answer

Comment: Same type and same values

Comment: Not in means for ex: a!=1 and a!=2 and etc.If your values same you get empty set.If you get any other error or exception please give us detailed information

Comment: First execute -> `SELECT cus_po_no FROM cus_comercial_invoice` What do you get?

Comment: Try using -> `select * from customer_purchase_order  where customer_purchase_order.purchase_id NOT IN (SELECT cus_comercial_invoice.cus_po_no FROM cus_comercial_invoice)`

Comment: i have already used this query.

Comment: What do you get ? SELECT cus_po_no FROM cus_comercial_invoice

Comment: cus_po_no is the reference of purchase_id

Comment: Then use join =>

`select * from customer_purchase_order  cpo JOIN cus_comercial_invoice cci ON cpo.purchase_id = cci.cus_po_no`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join Rows on foreign , primary key , use `JOIN`

```
select * from customer_purchase_order cpo JOIN 
cus_comercial_invoice cci 
ON cpo.purchase_id = cci.cus_po_no
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct, see this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42b9f/1) - it works as expected.